# cURL time out issues

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I am using libcurl to download some files from client to server. I have set the following options in my curl connection,

```
curl_easy_setopt(curlPtr, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(curlPtr, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME, 360);
curl_easy_setopt(curlPtr, CURLOPT_IGNORE_CONTENT_LENGTH, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(curlPtr, CURLOPT_TCP_NODELAY, 1);
```

Even though I have set to time out if no bytes received for 6 minutes (360 seconds), the operation gets timed out even if I am receiving the response,

This is the cURL debug response I received from this,

- Operation timed out after 360000 milliseconds with 205512 bytes received
- Closing connection #0
- Timeout was reached

I have redirected the response to a file and I can confirm the response bytes. But still the operation gets timed out after reaching exactly 6 minutes.

Can any one help me is there any thing I am wrong in the above ?

Note I am using libcurl 7.19.3. I can't do upgrade immediately but we have plans to do upgrade to latest stable release.

thanks,
Prabu

Comment: The server may will be timing you out and closing the connection (there is little you can do on the client end to stop that). It would be a security vulnerability for the server to leave a connection open if no data is flowing down it (an attacker could launch a DOS attack and just open many connections to the server eventually using all the connections available).

Comment: do you get any HTTP codes>

Comment: PS:  Most (integer) values passed to curl_easy_setopt should be longs. You are passing integers. This may be a problem in the future. Use `curl_easy_setopt(curlPtr, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME, 360L);`

Comment: Please find my post below and tell me is there any thing went wrong

Answer (score 1):

Nothing appears wrong in the *only* 4 lines that you posted.

By default, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT an CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS values are 0.
But if you use a specific curl implementation, try to pass these options to 0 in your code.

If it doesn't change anything, that is because it's a timeout on the web server. So if you don't have the control of this server, you can't do nothing. You must make a program with a loop to restart connection.